# Is is possible to have a stacked bar chart in Am Charts with Drill Down option?

Tags: charts, amcharts, stacked-chart

> I want to implement StackedBar chart,  and I want to drill down a column further into Bar chart. 
>   For example: One column represent a country, under a country we might have many states (stacked). If I click on any country column  then it should further drill down to Bar chart where each bar represent a single state. 
>   So the scenario is like From "Stacked Bar chart"  To  "Bar Chart"

Is it possible with AM Charts? 
I am not able to find it in documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First of all generate stacked bar chart. Now call chart.addListener method. This method is called when we click any of the bar. by using "event.index" we can get the INDEX of clicked BAR. Now call a separate Function by passing column index parameter. That new function will have following thing to do.
>    1. Hide stacked bar chart
>    2. Show new bar chart (Generate data for drilldown chart using parameter INDEX).

```
chart.addListener("clickGraphItem", function (event) {                        
         //Take the Index of Bar chart which has been clicked(eg: 0,1 2 etc..)
         //Call a function with column INDEX parameter
         //console.log(event.index); >> this will give index of chart 
         $scope.DrillChart(event.index);
    });

$scope.DrillChart =function(colid){
   //hide stack bar chart
   //Show simple bar chart
   //get the data for "colid"
   //Generate the Simple Bar Chart

}
```